# Converting gifv to jpg

Tags: convert, image-processing, imagemagick, gif

How can I convert .gifv to .jpg?

Is there also any script to capture the keyframe which is most informative?

```
jalal@klein:~$ convert -verbose -coalesce MRtIA77.gifv rabbit.jpg
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `GIFV' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `rabbit.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
jalal@klein:~$ convert  MRtIA77.gifv rabbit.jpg
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `GIFV' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `rabbit.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

Answer (score 2):

For the rabbit file, paste the following into your web browser ( I assume this is where you found the original video )

```
http://i.imgur.com/MRtIA77.gifv
```

Right click on the image (NOT the download link under the image) and choose "save video as"

Using ffmpeg you can extract frames from the video (below is set for 1 frame per second you can increase this number for more image captures per second)

```
ffmpeg -i MRtIA77.mp4 -vf fps=1 out%d.jpg
```

or png

```
ffmpeg -i MRtIA77.mp4 -vf fps=1 out%d.png
```

gifv is designed to simulate gif, but is not a type of gif. It is a .mp4 or .webm video.

**edit - those rabbits look more like Guinea Pigs to me